# Semantic Ui Menu not working

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

I am trying to work with semantic ui menu.

But I cannot get it to work, ie when I click the items in the menu, the active state isn't changing.
I didn't find any examples in the web either.

HTML :

```
<div class="ui grid">
        <div class="one wide row">
            <div class="ui green menu">
                <a class="active item">
                    <i class="home icon"></i> Home
                </a>
                <a class="item">
                    <i class="mail icon"></i> Messages
                </a>
                <div class="right menu">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="ui transparent icon input">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                            <i class="search link icon"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ui .green .menu').menu();
});
```

I have taken the code snippet from the semantic-ui website.

Some help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are down-voting, please leave a reason for doing so as a courtesy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here's a handler similar to the one on their demo site

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/148861909e6f528842ee354283a6a4c5)

screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

```
  $('.ui.green.menu')
    .on('click', '.item', function() {
      if(!$(this).hasClass('dropdown')) {
        $(this)
          .addClass('active')
          .siblings('.item')
            .removeClass('active');
      }
    });
```

Comment: np! glad to help. you'll do it for me someday.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ui.green.menu').menu();
});
```

Classes `ui`, `green` and `menu` are applied on the same element. They're not descendants of one another.

Answer (score 3):

To make your menu LIVE with jQuery use this.

From the [Semantic UI example](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/master/examples/components/menu.html)

```
$('.ui.menu .ui.dropdown').dropdown({
  on: 'hover'
});
$('.ui.menu a.item').on('click', function() {   
  $(this)
    .addClass('active')
    .siblings()
    .removeClass('active'); 
})
```