# Transitions and onClick actions in Semantic UI menus not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui

This is very much related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500376/semantic-ui-menu-not-working)

I'm new to Web Development, trying super hard, watching YouTube videos/Udemy/StackOverflow for answers.. Not sure if this is a duplicate..

I picked the code to write up a Menu from this [link](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html)

I have this HTML and I have two CDNs (one in the `head`, and the .js in the `body` as seen in a YouTube video.. Unfortunately.. No transitions, hovering activities are working as I see in the Semantic UI website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.3/semantic.min.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.3/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <div class="ui grid">
      <div class="four wide column">
        <div class="ui vertical fluid tabular menu">
          <a class="active item">
            Bio
          </a>
          <a class="item">
            Pics
          </a>
          <a class="item">
            Companies
          </a>
          <a class="item">
            Links
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="twelve wide stretched column">
        <div class="ui segment">
          This is an stretched grid column. This segment will always match the tab height
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

1. I would like a more detailed explanation to what other CDNs I need, or what JQuery, JavaScript, CSS files I require to get these transitions to work..
2. Is there a page that I go to that explains this? I know very basic JavaScript and I figured out that there was no function that would do all these activities..

Answer (score 1):

Semantic UI is heavily dependant on JQuery, so if you want to make it work (on the JavaScript part) you must add Jquery js files first, then Semantic UI js files, as stated on [Get Started](https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html#include-in-your-html) page of Semantic UI.
*As a good practice, always add JS files at the bottom of your HTML, right before the closing body tag.*

Here's your code with JQuery and Semantic UI:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.3/semantic.min.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="ui grid">
      <div class="four wide column">
        <div class="ui vertical fluid tabular menu">
          <a class="active item">
            Bio
          </a>
          <a class="item">
            Pics
          </a>
          <a class="item">
            Companies
          </a>
          <a class="item">
            Links
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="twelve wide stretched column">
        <div class="ui segment">
          This is an stretched grid column. This segment will always match the tab height
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.3/semantic.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

To use [Transition](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/transition.html) as a Module of Semantic UI you must call them using JQuery like the examples there.

I recommend you to internalize more in JQuery before learning Semantic UI, mainly because the way of using its components and modules, it's all related. Check out [Learn JQuery](https://learn.jquery.com) webpage and [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/lodge/learn-jquery/)'s video tutorials.
After that, dig deeper in Semantic UI by reading the documentation with all their sections, for example, the [Dropdown](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html) module has four sections: Definition, Examples, Usage and Settings.

Also, viewing this video of "[Semantic UI in 60 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9mUH1EWp40)" on Youtube could be useful to get to know better how Semantic UI works.

I hope that helps.